# Javascript async function return String not Promise

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a function which needs to be async (because of `await sleep()`) and I want it to **return a String not a Promise** by calling it from another non-async function.

```
async function _getString() {
    await sleep(50);
    return "Hello World";
}
// BY DOING THAT:
function getString() {
    return _getString().GET_PROMISE_VALUE();
}
```

I know currently of two possibility to get the value of the Promise:

1. `await getString()`
2. `getString().then((result) => {anotherVariable = result});`

The problem is:

- **I want to pause code execution where the function is called**, because then `anotherVariable` might get used before it gets assigned to `result`
- I don't want to use await because I would need another async function

Is there a way to make **getString()** wait until **_getString()** finished and then get the result?

Comment: Nope, using `.then` or `await` are the only real possibilities.

Comment: The only way to get an asynchronous result synchronously is with a time machine or a psychic - neither of which are present in javascript

Comment: Ok, i will see what i can do then. Thanks for your answers though! :)

Comment: Just in case it was not crystal clear -- functions defined with the `async` keyword *always*, *without exceptions* return `Promise` objects, in practice -- even with `return something` statements for any type and value of `something`. Your values are thus always "promisified" -- turned into a promise that resolves with the value you specify in a `return` statement. That's it, basically.